# Deal with overlapping @SessionAttributes names?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session

How can I make it so the `@SessionAttributes` are scoped to their respective controllers, or clean up the `@SessionAttributes` when switching workflows between controllers prematurely?

Example:

User goes to webpage to edit a dictionary and comes into `DictionaryController.java` which creates a `DictionaryForm.java` object and stores it in `@SessionAttributes` under "form"

Normally, the dictionary entry is fetched in a GET request, then updated on POST and `status.setComplete()` is called on success;

However if the user does the GET request, then clicks away to another page such as `OrganizationController.java` the second controller appears to try and reuse the "form" `@SessionAttribute` object from the other controller and will fail before it even reaches the `getOrganization()` method. (The nature of how exactly it's failing is undetermined as my eclipse console isn't outputting any exceptions, but I suspect it's because the form types don't match up)

```
@SessionAttributes("form")
public class DictionaryController {

    @ModelAttribute("form")
    public DictionaryForm initForm() {
        return new DictionaryForm();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Dictionary" method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDictionary(
        @ModelAttribute("form") DictionaryForm form) {
        ...
        return "dictionaryView";
    }    

    @RequestMapping(value="/Dictionary" method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateDictionary(
        @ModelAttribute("form") DictionaryForm form, 
        SessionStatus status) { 
        ...
        status.setComplete();
        return "successView";
    }

}
```

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("form")
public class OrganizationController{

    @ModelAttribute("form")
    public OrganizationForm initForm() {
        return new OrganizationForm();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Organization" method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getOrganization(
        @ModelAttribute("form") OrganizationForm form) {
        ...
        return "orgView";
    }    

    @RequestMapping(value="/Organization" method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateOrganization(
        @ModelAttribute("form") OrganizationForm form, 
        SessionStatus status) { 
        ...
        status.setComplete();
        return "successView";
    }
}
```

Comment: Workarounds I have thought of are:
Include entire form in html page through hidden inputs (possible data leakage ),
Load objects from database at every step (object loading is unfortunately often complex),
Use a different name for storing every form (heavy session clutter),
Manually manage session and explicitly deal with collisions in controller methods,
Make every form the same type (significant code rewrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I ended up using was having a `BaseForm` object type that all form types inherit from. Then in my request mapping methods for the GET requests, I would use `@ModelAttribute("form") BaseForm form` and manually check the form type in the body of the method, and if it doesn't match convert it and restore it in the session. (Replacing it in the session may be unnecessary if you attach it to your model object for the request)

ie.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/Organization" method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getOrganization(HttpServletRequest request,
        @ModelAttribute("form") BaseForm form) {
        if (form.getClass() != OrganizationForm.class) {
            form = new OrganizationForm();
            request.getSession().setAttribute("form", form);
        }
        ...
        return "orgView";
    }
```